# show my current location in google map with latitude and longitude value

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw path between my current location and chosen destination.But while accessing my current location using GPS_PROVIDER my last known location is shown instead of my current location.Here is the code for getting current location:

```
private LatLng getCurrentLatLng() {

        LatLng cloc = new LatLng(0, 0);
        LocationManager locman = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Location location = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Location Service Not Provided",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            cloc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            LatLng newp=onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locman.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 0, this);
        return cloc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);
        map.animateCamera(update);
        putOriginMarker(latlng);
    }
```

My mainfest.xml file contains the following permissions as suggested by Google's documentation:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Since I am using Google map v2.
Do anyone have idea?what is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just check below links may be it is useful for you. http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2013/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-showing.html & http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

Comment: Also try this link, http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ it's very comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `Location location = locman.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` this. `locman.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 0, this);`  is enough to get your current location.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Location mCurrentLocation;
 LocationClient mLocationClient;
 mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this,new myConnectionCallback(),new myConnectionListener());
 mLocationClient.connect();
 mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
 double longitudeC=mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
 double latitudeC=mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
```